# Panda_Merge multiple values in df1 to unique values in df2

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe (df1) with details of Genes and list of organs they are associated with and another mapping dataframe (df2) that mach these organs to unique organ type.

E.g.

df1 <-

```
data.frame ("Gene_name"=c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3, "Gene4"),   
"Organ_name"=c("Skin, Stomach, Eyes, Hair", "Lungs, Mouth, Oesophagus", "Pharynx, Lungs, Throat, Skin", "Stomach, Small intestine"))
```

df2 <-

```
data.frame ("Type"=c("External", "External", "External", "External"......"Internal", "Internal", "Internal"...),

 "Organ"=c("Skin", "Eyes", "Hair", "Legs",.... "Lungs", "Small intestine", "Oesophagus".....))
```

I want to see what major category individual genes belong to. **Is it frequently present internally or externally?**

If I split `"Organ_name"` using `str.split(",")` then in some cases I am getting around 20 columns. Merging these individual "Organ_name" columns of df1 with `"Type"` in df2 using Organ as the key is a big pain.

Is there a better way to analyse this data? How to know the frequency/count for `"Type"` of organ? Please let me know

Comment: I think you would find the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) collection useful.

Comment: FYI, the way in which you made your dataframes might work for `R` (if you fix the quotation mark problem), but not `pandas`. It would be helpful if you posted dataframes that can be used in python if you're looking for a `pandas` solution

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how you can structure your logic with `pandas`.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Gene_name": ("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4"),   
                    "Organ_name": ("Skin, Stomach, Eyes, Hair", "Lungs, Mouth, Oesophagus",
                                  "Pharynx, Lungs, Throat, Skin", "Stomach, Small intestine")})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Type": ("External", "External", "External", "External", "Internal", "Internal", "Internal"),
                    "Organ": ("Skin", "Eyes", "Hair", "Legs", "Lungs", "Small intestine", "Oesophagus")})
```

**Solution**

```
t = df2.set_index('Organ')['Type']

df1['Organ_list'] = df1['Organ_name'].str.split(', ')

df1['Int_Ext'] = [list(filter(None, map(t.get, x))) for x in df1['Organ_list']]

df1['Int_Ext_Flag'] = df1['Int_Ext'].apply(lambda x: 'Internal' if \
                      x.count('Internal') / len(x) >= 0.5 else 'External')
```

**Result**

```
  Gene_name                    Organ_name                      Organ_list  \
0     Gene1     Skin, Stomach, Eyes, Hair     [Skin, Stomach, Eyes, Hair]   
1     Gene2      Lungs, Mouth, Oesophagus      [Lungs, Mouth, Oesophagus]   
2     Gene3  Pharynx, Lungs, Throat, Skin  [Pharynx, Lungs, Throat, Skin]   
3     Gene4      Stomach, Small intestine      [Stomach, Small intestine]   

                          Int_Ext Int_Ext_Flag  
0  [External, External, External]     External  
1            [Internal, Internal]     Internal  
2            [Internal, External]     Internal  
3                      [Internal]     Internal
```

**Explanation**

- Create a mapping from organ to type using `df2`.
- Split the strings in `df1['Organ_list']` to form a list.
- Map elements of this list to type. Add logic to determine whether "Internal" or "External" via `pd.Series.apply`.
- In this example, I filter out organs which have not been mapped to type via `list(filter(None, ...))`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for.